# Azure ASE internal and external with express route for single web app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-ase

How to secure my app with ASE internal and external with express route for single web app. I am confused to choose the design with minimum cost to secure my single webapp.